# What is the alias name of Alfresco Certificate?

Tags: alfresco, solr4, alfresco-webscripts

i want to add alfresco certificate(browser.p12) into my keystore( /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts) for that i am converting my browser.p12 file into browser.pem file and try to add into my keystore but its telling **Input not an X.509 certificate**. i just search so i found that my alias name is not correct so just looking alias i run this command `keytool -list -keystore browser.p12` so its giving exception **Invalid keystore format** so can anyone tell me how to find the alias of alfresco default certificate or if anyone knows the alias name then please tell me.

Comment: As per [the Alfresco keystore docs](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/generate-repo-ssl-keystore.html), what happens if you add the option `-storetype JCEKS` when querying the current keystore?

Comment: when i am using this   '**keytool -list -v  -storetype JCEKS -keystore browser.p12'** then again its giving same exception as you can see below                                                **keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:709)
 at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1226)
 at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:789)
 at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
 at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)**

Comment: JCEKS is what the main keystore should be in. P12 = PKCS12 = something completely different! The docs I linked to does also give tips on importing from PKSC12

Comment: thanks Mr. Gagravarr i will also check the document that you suggested but the answer that i posted is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after a small struggle
i was passing wrong store type the correct store type is given below
**-storetype PKCS12**
and the alias name of the certificate is **ssl.repo**

Comment: Yuu should validate your answer as the correct solution.